# Can / should / how should I convert my Wordpress categories to tags?

Tags: tags, categories

My website uses Categories for work that I think belongs with tags.

How, perhaps with the [Better Search Replace plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/), can I convert all my Categories to corresponding tags?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial using a [different plugin](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-bulk-move-posts-to-categories-and-tags-in-wordpress/).

Comment: That tutorial said "Bulk Move plugin only moves your posts from one category or tag to another. It does not allow you to move categories to tags, tags to categories, or other custom taxonomies", but with a link to [Term Management Tools](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-merge-and-bulk-edit-categories-and-tags-in-wordpress/).